# Using an editor other than Visual Studio in UE4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

Is there any way that I can use an text editor/IDE other than VS for UE4? I sort of have a love-hate relationship with VS, I don't really appreciate how heavy it is and how glitchy it can be. I would feel a lot more comfortable using my trusty Dev-C++. If it isn't possible, I can manage, it isn't the end of the world, but it be nice if UE4 had this extent of flexibility, like unity.

Good day sirs, regards,
                           Luke Skywalker the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

If you alter the source of the engine editor, then you can probably make Dev C++ work. However, as of editor version 4.10, it only supports Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: i remembered i can just go into the source files and open them up with anything i want!